# GNUPLOT : how to stop "histeps" from terminating to zero (y=0) at start and endpoints?

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following script for plotting data points from file "delete.dat"

```
set terminal jpeg
set output "delete_histeps.jpeg"

set title "with histeps"
plot "delete.dat" using 1:2 index 0 pt 7 ps 0.2 lc "black" notitle,\
"delete.dat" using 1:2 index 1 pt 7 ps 0.2 lc "red" notitle,\
"delete.dat" using 1:2 index 2 pt 7 ps 0.2 lc "green" notitle,\
"delete.dat" using 1:2 index 0 with histeps lc "black",\
"delete.dat" using 1:2 index 1 with histeps lc "red",\
"delete.dat" using 1:2 index 2 with histeps lc "green"
```

and the "delete.dat" file is

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10


-1 5
-2 3
-3 4
-4 2
-5 6


5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
9 5
10 4
11 3
12 12
```

But the start and end step is dropping to zero, which I don't want. Though for ***step*** and ***fsteps*** command, the steps begin (end) at the first (last) data point, without dropping down to zero (y=0). Can you please suggest that works like ***histeps*** (which keeps data points in the middle of the steps) but does not terminate to zero (like ***steps*** or ***fsteps***). I'm also attaching pictures.

[image: With histeps]

[image: With steps]

[image: With fsteps]

Answer (score 1):

If your data points are equidistant (like the ones you provided), an alternative hack would be possible as well by combining `fsteps` and `steps` and shifting the x-value by half the point-to-point-distance:

```
plot "delete.dat" i 0 pt 7 ps 2 lc "black" not, \
'' i 1 pt 7 ps 2 lc "red" not, \
'' i 2 pt 7 ps 2 lc "green" not, \
'' u ($1-1.0):2 i 0 w steps lc "black", '' u ($1+1.0):2 i 0 w fsteps lc "black" not, \
'' u ($1+0.5):2 i 1 w steps lc "red", '' u ($1-0.5):2 i 1 w fsteps lc "red" not, \
'' u ($1-0.5):2 i 2 w steps lc "green", '' u ($1+0.5):2 i 2 w fsteps lc "green" not
```

The trick here is that `steps` or `fsteps` alone would miss either the last or the first point and the line would end in mid-air, therefore both have to be plotted on top of each other with the same plotting style.

One must take care of the correct sign: if x is positive, `steps` get a downshift and `fsteps` get an upshift; and vice-versa if x is negative.

My answer is definitely not as "robust" as the one of theozh, but maybe easier to understand.

Comment: this is golden.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's how `hispteps`, `steps`, and `fsteps` have been defined.
Then, you have to create your own steps. A solution could be the following:

**Code:** (improved version)

```
### steps like histeps but not dropping to zero
reset session
set colorsequence classic

$Data <<EOD
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10


-1 5
-2 3
-3 4
-4 2
-5 6


5 1
6 2
7 3
8 4
9 5
10 4
11 3
12 12
EOD

set table $myStep
    do for [i=0:2] {
        plot $Data u ($0==0?(x1=x2=$1):(x1=x2,x2=$1),(c=$0,x1+x2)/2.):2 index i w table
        plot $Data u 1:2 every ::c index i w table     # add last value
        plot '+' u ("") every ::::1 w table            # add two empty lines
    }
unset table

set key top left
plot for [i=0:2] $myStep u 1:2 index i w step lc i lw 3 notitle,\
     for [i=0:2] $Data u 1:2 index i w p pt 7 lc i notitle, \
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]